# Exception accessing registry path in CurrentUser

Tags: vb.net

I would need some help with a little code snippet in Visual Studio 2008
A constructor should initialize the member var "reg".

But after checking a certain registry path in the CurrentUser branch, it stays undefined and an exception is thrown.

```
Private reg As RegistryKey

Public Sub New ()
[...]
Try

            If Not Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ", True) Is Nothing Then

                reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ" & _WindowsUserName, True)

            Else
                reg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ" & _WindowsUserName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            End If
            If reg Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Registry-Exception")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

[...]
End Sub
```

Thank you, in advance
Stephan

Comment: FYI you can download, for free, much newer versions of Visual Studio than 2008. Look for the "community edition".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
If Not Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ", True) Is Nothing Then

                reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ" & _WindowsUserName, True)

            Else
                reg = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ" & _WindowsUserName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            End If
            If reg Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Registry-Exception")
```

In the if you are checking to see if the sub key XYZ exists, but when you are trying to open it you are appending the _WindowsUserName, which might not exist.

If you change your If statement to be:

```
If Not Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ProgramName\XYZ" & _WindowsUserName, True) Is Nothing Then
```

it should cure the exception.